# Hackerrank 30 Days of Code - Day 8 & C# -Runtime Error

Tags: c#, dictionary, maps

I am participating in 30 days of code at C#. I am on 8.Day (Dictionaries and Maps). I go to run my code and Test Case 0, Test Case 2, Test Case 3, Test Case 4 is successful but Test Case 1 is not successful. Hackerrank shows me about error "Runtime Error". I don't understand this error. Thank You.

**Challenge: Hackerrank Day 8 Dictionaries and Maps**

Can anyone figure out why my code for this exercise from Python Hackerrank 30 Days of Challenge doesn't pass Test Case 1?

Here is the challenge:

Objective Today, we're learning about Key-Value pair mappings using a Map or Dictionary data structure. Check out the Tutorial tab for learning materials and an instructional video!

Task Given names and phone numbers, assemble a phone book that maps friends' names to their respective phone numbers. You will then be given an unknown number of names to query your phone book for. For each queried, print the associated entry from your phone book on a new line in the form name=phoneNumber; if an entry for is not found, print Not found instead.

Note: Your phone book should be a Dictionary/Map/HashMap data structure.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer, , denoting the number of entries in the phone book. Each of the subsequent lines describes an entry in the form of space-separated values on a single line. The first value is a friend's name, and the second value is an -digit phone number.

After the lines of phone book entries, there are an unknown number of lines of queries. Each line (query) contains a to look up, and you must continue reading lines until there is no more input.

Note: Names consist of lowercase English alphabetic letters and are first names only.

Output Format

On a new line for each query, print Not found if the name has no corresponding entry in the phone book; otherwise, print the full and in the format name=phoneNumber.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var phoneBook = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var entry = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            var name = entry[0];
            var phone = int.Parse(entry[1]);
            phoneBook.Add(name, phone);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            if (phoneBook.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                var phone = phoneBook[name];
                Console.WriteLine($"{name}={phone}");
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Input (stdin)

```
100000
unayklejwm 53561825
ahiff 57272140
frlrecdfxo 28001354
aeccxyrbek 21112785
mlgdk 12405837
iyiyycfngr 23841264
subnwvrqdp 77688226
vhypdqfbdy 67846211
lcnbh 86026675
lxbjpmuhis 85475547
enfifbprov 20172436
hnjctgslxf 18125412
slfoglbvah 47530087
mpsrcmrkon 44365224
jnpslqvlkx 88071512
liwyjbsfkk 50646067
kyrkhaikuf 18535535
ubvfx 43551151
krger 80787433{-truncated-}
```

Expected Output

```
Not found
ipwpabdefa=14170412
Not found
toykmviqbo=11872347
mooetebtqt=70658483
fbubawkkhq=10613664
Not found
ejqxn=77321147
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
xgfpx=58118174
Not found
odacddldrk=73267266
Not found
iakxugylkc=41875647
Not found
djtelththc=20278224
Not found{-truncated-}
```

Conclusion

```
Runtime Error :/
```

How should I fix my code?

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The question clearly says "there are an unknown number of lines of queries". You are however looping up to n instead of reading up to the end of the file.

If you can see the output (out and err) of your code, add a try-catch block inside your main method and see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I completed this tasks.

Here my code:

```
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution */
    int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Dictionary <string, string> phonebook = new Dictionary <string, string>();
        
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        string[] line = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        phonebook[line[0]] = line[1];
    }
        
    string name;
    while ((name = Console.ReadLine()) != null){
        if (phonebook.ContainsKey(name))
            Console.WriteLine(name + "=" + phonebook[name]);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not found");
    }
}
```